# Lua loading variables when calling program ~ Parameter?

Tags: variables, load, lua

I recently got into Computer Craft (Mod for Minecraft) you can code the computers with lua.

I want to go "water status" and it will load "water" and then set a variable to "status" or any other word/string in its place so I can use it for anything. I guess you would call that a parameter?

```
os.run( environment, prgmpath, arguments )
```

I don't understand what environment is. prgmpath is water and the argument would be status?
I'm just unsure how to grab those arguments from that.

So yeah, I'm quite confused =/

Tried to explain it best I could, thanks,
Jazza

After searching around, I think I found my answer.

```
lua water arg1
```

Goes in the command line

```
derp = arg[2]
```

Goes in the file?

EDIT: After lurking around some more, I found out that:

```
derp = ...
print(derp)
```

In the file and:

```
file hi
```

It printed hi, so I guess that works, but I can't seem to add any more D=

Answer (score 1):

os.run is an extension to the os library written specifically for that mod. according to the documentation on the wiki:

- environment is the metatable to set up the state for the script you're running at prgmpath
- arguments is whatever you want to pass to the code you're calling located in the script at prgmpath

so basically, if you had some code set up to do something specific in path/to/file.lua, but it depended on some outside state, you'd set up that state in your calling file, and pass the environment (or a subset of it) to the code in file.lua by passing it as a table to the first param in os.run().

arguments is supposed to be a table of arguments you wanted to pass to the function you'd be calling in file.lua. so if in file.lua you had...

```
function doSomething(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    ...
end
```

you'd pass arg1, arg2, and arg3 to doSomething by creating a table and passing it like this...

```
local args = {"arg1Val", {}, 1234}
os.run({}, '/path/to/file.lua', args)
```

os.run would then set up an empty environment for function doSomething() in file.lua, and pass the 3 values in args to the function.

make sense?

Comment: Well thank you for taking the time to write it out, but I don't really understand, if you could make a small demo and just label what does what? EDIT: I understand the last line, but I don't understand what" {"arg1Val", {}, 1234}" means =/

Comment: After looking around some more, I kind of understand it.
Basically All I want to know now is how to run that from the terminal.

Comment: local args are the values that get passed to the doSomething function, the table is unpacked so that doSomething would get the values arg1="arg1Val", arg2=an empty table, and arg3=1234